# Override functions in /_core/js/product.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to customize the behavior of a function in `product.js` under `/_core/js`. The function declaration is:

```
function replaceAddToCartSections(data) {}
```

I tried by creating a function with the same name in `custom.js`.  Since this one is the last js file loaded in the HTML, I thought the original function would be overriden, but that wasn't the result.

When I print `replaceAddToCartSections.toString()` in Mozilla dev tools, I get my new function. However, when I remove the function from `custom.js`, I get :

> ReferenceError: replaceAddToCartSections is not defined

Are the functions of `core.js` private? How to override them? Is is something relative to Webpack configuration?

Comment: Which PS version are you running?

Comment: @joseantgv , this is relative to Prestashop starting from 1.7.4.2 at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after `replaceAddToCartSections` is called, `updatedProduct` is emitted, so you can define a function like:

```
prestashop.on('updatedProduct', function (event) {
    // your code
})
```

Comment: This is, IMO, not overriding, but working in my case. Thanks.

Comment: @AdibAroui You are right, you are not overriding but it is the correct way to do it. This way it would also work if `replaceAddToCartSections()` function is modified in next PS versions without modifying yours.

Comment: @AdibAroui it would be like a hook in JS